# Pandas only return Value from Cell

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, jupyter, jupyter-lab

I am currently trying to retrieve values from cells in a Dataframe. I am searching through a dataframe to find strings that match values in a column in a row, then returning a value in that row from another column.

My code looks like this:

```
df:
Fruit   Value
apple     7.0
banana    6.0
orange    8.0
lemon     3.0
melon     2.0

myList = ['apple', 'lemon']

result = []

for word in myList:

    result.append(df['Value'].loc[df['Fruit'] == word].values)

print(result)
```

The print statement is outputting:

```
[array([], dtype=float64), array([7.0]), array([], dtype=float64), array([3.0])]
```

My desired output is simply an array of float values:

```
[7.0, 3.0]
```

How would I go about cleaning my output to achieve this? My end goal is to get the average value of the array.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [`Series.isin`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.isin.html) with [`boolean indexing`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/indexing.html#boolean-indexing) and convert to list:

```
print (df.loc[df['Fruit'].isin(myList), 'Value'].values.tolist())
[7.0, 3.0]
```

> My end goal is to get the average value of the array.

Then better is call `mean` of filtered `Series`:

```
val = df.loc[df['Fruit'].isin(myList), 'Value'].mean()
print (val)
5.0
```